# Automatically search for YouTube contents in Java / Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'll write a program in Java or Javascript to continoulsy get a list of videos from YouTube that matches specified metadata as name, comments and so on.

YouTube use its own search engine that is totally separate from the Google search engine.

Please anyone can help address me to some libraries, API, or other ?

Thank you in advance.
Ivano C.

Comment: So use the youtube-api that you tagged the question with? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These can help you to search list of videos from Youtube. 
Please refer these links:

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/#data_api
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/getting-started-with-youtube-java-api.html
```